# Increment or Decrement volume programmatically on Xiaomi device adjusts it by 10 steps instead of one step

Tags: android, debugging, xiaomi

Does anyone know about this bug or how to solve it?

I found this issue on Xiaomi 12 lite 5g with Android 13.

I'm using the following code which works on other devices:

```
        mAudioManager = getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager

            mAudioManager.adjustStreamVolume(
                AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER,
                0
            )
            mAudioManager.adjustStreamVolume(
                AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE,
                0
            )
```